# How to create a repeater field that contains another repeater field in Redux from WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, redux

I tried to nest the repeaters as per the usual array structure that Redux supports, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

```
array(
                'id'             => 'faq_tabs_title',
                'type'           => 'repeater',
                'title'          => esc_html__( 'Faq Tabs Title', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                // 'subtitle'       => esc_html__( '', 'your-textdomain-here' ),
                // 'desc'           => esc_html__( '', 'your-textdomain-here' ),
                'group_values' => true, // Group all fields below within the repeater ID
                //'item_name'    => '', // Add a repeater block name to the Add and Delete buttons
                'bind_title'   => '', // Bind the repeater block title to this field ID
                // 'static'       => 3, // Set the number of repeater blocks to be output
                // 'limit'        => 3, // Limit the number of repeater blocks a user can create
                //'sortable'     => false, // Allow the users to sort the repeater blocks or not
                'fields'         => array(
                    array(
                        'id'          => 'title_field',
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Title', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id'             => 'faq_tabs_title',
                        'type'           => 'repeater',
                        'title'          => esc_html__( 'Faq Tabs List', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                        // 'subtitle'       => esc_html__( '', 'your-textdomain-here' ),
                        // 'desc'           => esc_html__( '', 'your-textdomain-here' ),
                        'group_values' => true, // Group all fields below within the repeater ID
                        //'item_name'    => '', // Add a repeater block name to the Add and Delete buttons
                        'bind_title'   => '', // Bind the repeater block title to this field ID
                        // 'static'       => 3, // Set the number of repeater blocks to be output
                        // 'limit'        => 3, // Limit the number of repeater blocks a user can create
                        //'sortable'     => false, // Allow the users to sort the repeater blocks or not
                        'fields'         => array(
                            array(
                                'id'          => 'text_field',
                                'type'        => 'text',
                                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Text', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Is there a native way or a workaround to achieve this nested repeater structure in the Redux Framework?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!